# How do I configure VS Code to enable code completion on .json files (jsonschema support)?

Tags: json, jsonschema, visual-studio-code

In the [Visual Studio Code demo](http://video.ch9.ms/sessions/build/2015/3-680-LG.mp4) at minutes 28:57-29:20 and 30:20-31:10, some cool JSON code completion is shown.

Where and how do I add a schema for my JSON files to a project?

How does VS Code know which schema to use for a given `.json` file?

Comment: This link might help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/11/intellisense-for-json-schema-in-the-json-editor.aspx

Comment: Michael, I have updated my answer. Isn't it what you are looking for? I believe your question was expecting whereabouts of JSON Schema to get intellisense, especially in VS Code.

Comment: If no, I would like what was not aligned\ working in my answer.

Comment: @AshokanSivapragasam - It is not a matter of whether your answer works, it is a matter of whether your answer work in all use cases - in particular, the OP's original case.  The ability to add a level of indirection was specifying a URL was built into vscode for a reason. (Se my comment to your answer for details.)  I hope this makes you feel better.

Comment: @CraigHicks, Yes, I think my answer is aligned to some other question which expects the code completion for standalone json files by schema. :)

Answer (score 30):

The association of JSON schemas to files is done in the settings (File, Preferences, User Settings or Workspace Settings), under the property 'json.schemas'.

This is an example how the JSON schema for bower is associated to the bower schema.

```json
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/bower.json",
            "/.bower.json"
        ],
        "url": "http://json.schemastore.org/bower"
    },
    ...
```

You can also use schemas located in your workspace or define a schema right in the settings itself. Check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json for examples.

Comment: To share the settings with team members, I have to save it as workspace settings and check the .settings/settings.json into the (git/SVN...) repository.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in two cases: 1. when I have a submodule which contains its own `.settings/settings.json` (it is not considered). 2. if I open a subdirectory, then the `.settings/settings.json` in a parent directory is ignored as well.
I think it should work like `.gitignore`, `.jshint` etc. Else we are back in the world of old rigid IDEs.

Comment: It would be nice if the documentation would explain what patterns can be used (e.g. `**.foo.json`)

Comment: @martin-aeschlimann do you know how to make it works if we need autosuggestion from the project root folder itself? 
We have whole project repo with the only JSON files and we need to VSCODE to 
 reference project root and all its JSON files to suggest JSON keys while writing new .json file?

Answer (score 24):

You can refer your JSON Schema in $schema node and get your intellisense in VS Code right away. No need to configure anywhere else.

For example,

```json
{
   "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/coffeelint",
   "line_endings": "unix"
}
```

[image: Json Schema Intellisense]

This is the intellisense I was talking about. JSON Schema has the list of possible JSON properties in your current cursor position and VS Code can pull out that list of intellisense.

Note that, every official JSON should have a concrete JSON Schema to prove the data integrity. This answer is still valid!

Comment: Good point so here is the resource to adding a schema directly to a JSON file https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_mapping-in-the-json

Comment: Schema ids are just URIs. So unless VSCode can lookup the schema from some global server or read the id itself as a URL, this may not work.

Comment: @ChristopherBarber, VS Code and VS downloads the schema from server or local file and it suggests of list of possible JSON elements from your current cursor position in JSON file. How do you think if does not work? It worked for me

Comment: @ChristopherBarber, JSON Schema Tagging faciliates intellisense for writing JSON data while abiding to JSON Schema.

Comment: My point is that a schema id does not necessarily have to refer to an actual file location or URL that can be read. You may have to look it up in some sort of database to find the actual schema definition. Is there a way to configure that?

Comment: @ChristopherBarber, I have updated my answer. Isn't it what you are looking for? I believe OP's question was expecting whereabouts of JSON Schema to get intellisense, especially in VS Code.

Comment: Nope. Like I said, you can have some arbitrary URI as your scheme identifier `https://my-domain.com/this-url-does-not-exist`. In that case, you have to tell VS Code where to find the actual schema with that identifier. Your example works only for the case where the scheme entry can be read directly.

Comment: Well, in your case, you are supposed to refer JSON Schema from somewhere else. Why can't you refer that in the JSON file itself? **Seriously, why would you refer non-existent Schema URI from JSON file and refer the real accessible Schema file from other point?** How does it makes sense to you?

Comment: although this works, it gives a warning `Property $schema is not allowed.`

Comment: Reasons why this answer is not the only answer: (1) '$schema' itself may not be a valid property, e.g, when schema support is added to to existing software. (2) A level of indirection in specifying the schema URI offers flexibility, e.g., for development a local URI may be preferred because the schema is changing rapidly, or if the URI changes to a new one, it can be updated at the system/project/user level rather updating every single file.    Vscode deliberately built in the feature to allow a level of indirection .  It was not an accidental mistake.

Answer (score 16):

The three ways I've got VS Code to use a JSON schema are ...

*So for something like the Azure Function schema from* ... http://json.schemastore.org

```
"json.schemas": [
  {
    "fileMatch": [
      "/function.json"
    ],
    "url": "http://json.schemastore.org/function"
  }
]
```

1. In **User Settings"**, i.e. as an element in the users `settings.json` in 'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Code\User'
2. In the **"Workspace Settings"**, then in it's the "settings" section in the `.code-workspace` file ... *assuming your're using a VS Code Workspace*
3. In the **"Folder Settings"**, it's "settings" section in the `settings.json`, which is in the `.vscode` directory  ... *assuming your're using a VS Code Workspace*

The Folder takes precedence over Workspace, and Workspace over User

And the Workspace and Folder work with relative paths, e.g. in the `.code-workspace` file ...

```
"settings": {
  "json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": [
        "/task.json"
      ],
      "url": "./schema/tasks.schema.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

or in the Folder Settings `settings.json` in `\.vscode\` ...

```
"json.schemas": [
  {
    "fileMatch": [
      "/task.json"
    ],
    "url": "./schema/tasks.schema.json"
  }
]
```