# Can i force a type to a json file?

Tags: node.js, typescript

recently i've been asked to implement config files for my system, config for each environment.
When i wanted to use the config i noticed that i dont have it typed, at least not in easy way..
So i created an index file which import and export the config adding an interface to it.

I wonder if i can add a type to my config (somehow) which will force the developers to stick to it and also provide us a type at compilation time.

Its like to have a config.ts file instead of config.json (maybe that what i should do?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can - use [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) for this purpose.

To ensure your develpers have not messed up the data - use one of many available validators (i find [this one](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4) to work pretty nice) to verify json object you read from config file.

Some IDE (vscode for example) support json schemas and [can validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056721/how-do-i-configure-vs-code-to-enable-code-completion-on-json-files-jsonschema) it on the fly.

You can have your config stored in *.ts file as exported const variable. Then after requiring it verify it with validator. Unfortunately this approach will not give you errors at compilation type.