# vscode - is there a way to PREVENT schema cache from being cleared when offline?

Tags: visual-studio-code, caching, jsonschema

If I have vscode open for several hours but remain offline, it seems the schema cache automatically clears and I get errors like this:

> Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig': getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN json.schemastore.org.

Is there a way to PREVENT schema cache from being cleared when offline? Two specific situations are

- vscode is open throughout the transition from online to offline
- vscode is opened while offline

I know it could be done manually (c.f. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53616846/4376643)), e.g., by copying a a version for offline use and specifying in `settings.json`

```
    "json.schemas": [
      {
        "fileMatch": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "url": "./tsconfig.schema.json"
      }
    ],
```

but of course I'd rather the existing schema cache feature worked sensibly - and maybe it does but requires a switch to do so?